# Bazel rules_docker push container with Docker image SHA-256 tag

Tags: docker, bazel, docker-registry, bazel-rules

I would like to push a Docker image to a registry with as tag the SHA-256 digest of the image. I am using Bazel and more specifically [`container_push`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#container_push) from [docker_rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/). Unfortunately, I am unable to retrieve the image's digest and tag the image with it.

Assuming I have the following *BUILD.bazel* config, how can I do this?

```
go_image(
    name = "image",
    embed = [":app1_lib"],
    goarch = "amd64",
    goos = "linux",
)

container_push(
    name = "publish",
    format = "Docker",
    image = ":image",
    registry = DOCKER_REGISTRY,
    repository = "app1",
    skip_unchanged_digest = True,
    tag = "{ ??? }",
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the `basel-out` folder contained for my target a file called `image.json.sha256`. Using this in the `tag_file` property from `container_push` produces the expected tag.

```
go_image(
    name = "image",
    embed = [":app1_lib"],
    goarch = "amd64",
    goos = "linux",
)

container_push(
    name = "publish",
    format = "Docker",
    image = ":image",
    registry = DOCKER_REGISTRY,
    repository = "app1",
    skip_unchanged_digest = True,
    tag_file = "image.json.sha256",
)
```

Comment: Thanks. tag_file = "<image_label>.json.sha256"