# How to tag container_image dynamically?

Tags: docker, bazel, bazel-rules

I am a bit new to the Bazel world.
My goal is to tag and push images to the registry but with a dynamic tag.
Without Bazel, I used to suffix my version with git commit SHA(6-7 chars), ex. `1.0.0-a68hg4`
I want to do the same with the container_push rule.

```
container_push(
    name = "publish",
    format = "Docker",
    image = ":image",
    registry = DOCKER_REGISTRY,
    repository = "app1",
    skip_unchanged_digest = True,
    tag_file = "image.json.sha256",
)
```

code copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536508/bazel-rules-docker-push-container-with-docker-image-sha-256-tag).
I can use SHA which makes my tag unique between builds, but can I join strings to make something as I want. I.e. `1.0.0-a68h4` (<a_const_str>-<SHA256_6_char>

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `Brain Silverman` for the detailed answer.

If anyone is looking for an easy solution, here it is.

`build.sh`(script to push docker images to registry)

```
version="1.0.0"

docker login -u "$USERNAME" -p "$PASSWORD" "$REGISTRY"

bazel run --workspace_status_command="echo VERSION $version-$(git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c 1-8)" //docker: publish
```

`BUILD.bazel`

```
container_push(
    name = "publish",
    format = "Docker",
    image = ":image",
    registry = DOCKER_REGISTRY,
    repository = "app1",
    skip_unchanged_digest = True,
    tag_file = "{VERSION}",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the git commit via [stamping](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#workspace_status), which is [supported by rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#stamping). For example, put this in `workspace_status.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "STABLE_GIT_COMMIT $(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

Then if you build with `--workspace_status_command=workspace_status.sh` you can write `tag = "something-{STABLE_GIT_COMMIT}"` (and set `stamp = True` on the `container_push`). `git describe` instead of `git rev-parse` could be useful to include the name of the current tag or branch if you want that.

If you want to combine that and the sha256, I'd use a genrule to create a file like this:

```py
genrule(
    name = "create_tag_file",
    srcs = [
        "image.json.sha256",
    ],
    stamp = True,
    outs = [ "my_tag_file" ],
    cmd = "cat $(location image.json.sha256) > $@ && cat bazel-out/volatile-status.txt | grep STABLE_GIT_COMMIT | awk '{print $2}' >> $@",
)

container_push(
    <same as before>
    tag_file = ":my_tag_file",
)
```

Writing a script in a separate file (put it in `tools` and use `$(location)` to get the location of it to run) will make the string manipulation easier to read than putting it all inline in the `cmd` attribute like this.

If you want to add an arbitrary identifying string as part of the tag, [--embed_label](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--embed_label) on the bazel command line will set the `BUILD_EMBED_LABEL` key in stable-status.txt.

Answer (score 0):

For snapshots I rather recommend versioning based on SHA256 of source files. With this approach new tag will be published only when content of image really changes.

Take a look on https://github.com/mgosk/bazel-scala-example/blob/master/example-bin/BUILD

```
# https://github.com/mgosk/bazel-scala-example/blob/master/example-bin/BUILD
git_tag_with_sha_multitargets(
    name = "version",
    targets = [
        ":image",
        "@java_base//image",
    ],
)

container_push(
    name = "image-push",
    format = "Docker",
    image = ":image",
    registry = "docker.io",
    repository = "mgosk/example-bin",
    tag_file = ":version",
)

# https://github.com/mgosk/bazel-scala-example/blob/master/tools/version.bzl
def git_tag_with_sha_multitargets(name, targets, postfix = "", **kwargs):
    super_stable_status = "//:super_stable_status"
    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = targets + [super_stable_status],
        outs = [name + ".txt"],
        cmd = """
            STABLE_RELEASE_VERSION=$$(cat $(location """ + super_stable_status + """) | grep 'STABLE_RELEASE_VERSION' | awk '{print $$2}' || :)
            POSTFIX=""" + postfix + """
            if [[ -z "$$STABLE_RELEASE_VERSION" ]]; then
              SHA256=$$(sha256sum $(location """ + " ) $(location ".join(targets) + """) | awk '{print $$1;}' | sha256sum | awk '{print $$1;}')
              echo $$SHA256-SNAPSHOT > $(OUTS);
            else
              echo $$STABLE_RELEASE_VERSION$$POSTFIX > $(OUTS);
            fi
            """,
        **kwargs
    )
```